# Dataset inactive when shown from button action

Tags: bugs, front-end, dataset, button

**Bug introduced in 11.1.1 (or earlier) and persisting through 11.3, fixed in 12.1 or earlier**

> CASE:3919858

---

This dataset is active:

```
Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>]
```

[image: active dataset]

by active I mean that you can click on it to explore deeper levels. Notice how the cursor becomes a hand and the text becomes blue on mouse over. And if you click on it, you get:

[image]

For some reason the following commands result in datasets that are inactive:

```
Button["test", 
    CreateDocument[
        {ExpressionCell[
             Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>],
             "Output"]}]]
```

and even simpler:

```
Button["test", 
    CellPrint[
        ExpressionCell[
            Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>], 
            "Output"]]]
```

This is how an inactive dataset looks like:

[image: inactive datase]

My questions are:

1. Why is the interactivity of the dataset lost?
2. Is there a way
   to preserve it for the cases shown?

I am using Mathematica 11.1.1 under Windows 7.

Comment: I hate that I can't explain it! :)

Comment: @kuba then it must be a good question! I contacted support (CASE:3919858), they reproduced it and proposed a workarround using NotebookWrite, SelectionMove and SelectionEvaluate. Do you think this should be tagged as a bug?

Comment: I don't work with `Datasets` as I find the formatting unpredicatable anyway so it is hard to judge for me. What I find interesting is at what stage is this hyperlink added/dropped that it is affected by button, even "Queued" one.

Comment: All examples (including the first) are inactive in MMA 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit). If I click on `2 levels`, I get TypeSystem`Struct[{"a", "b"}, {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Assoc[TypeSystem`Atom[TypeSystem`Enumeration["b1", "b2"]], TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], 2]}].

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on **13.2** on a mac and I am uploading a screen recording.

[image]

The commands are the same as in the OP and I am providing them below as well for completeness

```
Quit[]

Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>]

Button["test", 
 CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[
    Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>], 
    "Output"]}]]

Button["test", 
 CellPrint[
  ExpressionCell[
   Dataset[<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> <|"b1" -> 1, "b2" -> 2|>|>], "Output"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

as the picture shows, 12.1 works.

[image]

[image]